# Is it possible to make a GitHub Page from a subfolder HTML file?

Tags: github-pages

I have a large GitHub repository, "My_Learning_Port," which has multiple subfolders in which I have different HTML/CSS/JS code examples. I want to be able to make a specific GitHub page for each code example in these subfolders. But am I only able to make a GitHub page from the main GitHub repository?

For example, I have this filepath to an HTML/JS "Assessment" example: `https://github.com/<username>/My_Learning_Port/blob/main/JavaScript/JS_First_Steps/Assessment/index.html`

I set up a GitHub Page for the initial repository, with this filepath: `https://<username>.github.io/My_Learning_Port` but when I attach the filepath mentioned above on the end of this URL, I get a 404 message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try following the actual file path**, which is also shown above the `index.html` code,  **instead of the file path mentioned in the GitHub URL, as they might vary.**
[image: GitHub file directory]

```
 https://<username>.github.io/My_Learning_Port/<sub-folder-1>/<sub-folder-2>/<sub-folder-3>/index.html
```

After putting the values:

https://andrewsrea.github.io/My_Learning_Port/JavaScript/JS_First_Steps/Assessment/index.html

This is where your page is hosted.

Comment: Ah! Omit the `/blob/main/`. Thank you!

Comment: Glad, that helped :)

Answer (score 1):

well, as I know that s impossible for now. you should split your Learning pot to repos and try it that way. that should be good even for the repos where every repo is nicely documented.